# Get DHCP IP but can't ping anything using connectx2 and Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking

Fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04

My Mellanox ConnectX2 single port NIC is detected and gets a proper IP, subnet mask, and default gateway from DHCP. "ip link" shows the NIC as up. Link speed is the proper 10Gb.

My issue is that I have no actual network connectivity. I'm unable to ping the default gateway or 8.8.8.8.

I'm fairly new to Linux so I'm unsure how to troubleshoot further.
This same server, nic, switch, and DHCP server was working when I was booting esxi so I'm confident the issue is OS related.

Comment: Rarely does `8.8.8.8` respond to ping requests. Can you update your question to include the output of `ip a`? This might help someone provide some specific support 

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot. The switch port was previously configured to only accept vlan tagged packets (which esxi was doing). Works perfectly now that I configured the switch to accept untagged packets.